# .net regular expression returning 2 results where I only want 1

Tags: .net, regex

Trying to extract a US phone number (in any format) from mixed character value, returning only ONE or ZERO results with .NET regular expression.

> **Example:**  yyy666 555 5555yyyy1

The pattern `(?<!\d)\(?([\d]{3})*\)?[\s-]?[\d]{3}[\s-]?[\d]{4}(?!\d)` is returning:

> "666 555 5555", "666".

I do not want the second result "666" (which contains only the area code), there should only be ONE result or ZERO Results (IE. the return for that example should only be a full phone number "666 555 5555" or nothing).

What am I missing/how do I make it return 0 or 1 results?

Comment: I think that if you do not want the second result, which is capture group 1 then you shouldn't read it. There is no need to change the expression if you don't want to, you can just simply not read it. What does your code look like?

Comment: Fact is you may need the parts at some time in the future `(?<!\d)\(?([\d]{3})*\)?[\s-]?([\d]{3})[\s-]?([\d]{4})(?!\d)` no need to make a different expression. As always, group0 is the entire match, but you may want to reformat it with the parts, which is what I would do.

Comment: Valid point, in fact that is what the developer I am working with said we could do. I am not a developer and don't have access to the code as I am just assisting in the creation of regular expressions for specific data fields like phone numers, dates, etc. for an (zonal) OCR project we are doing. Thanks a bunch for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part `([\d]{3})*\)` causes a group capture, and that's your "666".

You can avoid that, either with:

```
(?<!\d)\(?(?:[\d]{3})*\)?[\s-]?[\d]{3}[\s-]?[\d]{4}(?!\d)
```

where the `(?:...)` means non-capturing group, or by using an explicit capture flag for your regex:

```
new Regex("...", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```